# using the default value if the parameter is null

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I write the code block marked in the picture below more properly. My goal is to send the default value to the parameter if the **availableColors** variable is null.

[Code Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfQDE.png)

```dart
showDialog<Color>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        return ResponsiveDialog(
          context: context,
          title: title,
          headerColor: headerColor,
          headerTextColor: headerTextColor,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          buttonTextColor: buttonTextColor,
          child: availableColors == null ? BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          ): BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            availableColors: availableColors,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          ),  
          okPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(selectedColor),
        );
      },
    );
  },
).then((selection) {
  if (onChanged != null && selection != null) onChanged(selection);
});
```

I can't change BlockPicker. It comes from an external library.

```dart
class BlockPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const BlockPicker({
    @required this.pickerColor,
    @required this.onColorChanged,
    this.availableColors = _defaultColors,
    this.layoutBuilder = defaultLayoutBuilder,
    this.itemBuilder = defaultItemBuilder,
  });
```

Comment: Just so you know in the future its better to post your code in text format that in a picture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, when invoking a function, Dart does not provide a good way to conditionally use its default argument. (There is at least [one language proposal to provide such a mechanism](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/219).)

In general, you'd usually have to duplicate the function's default argument (and hope it doesn't change).

In this case, `BlockPicker` doesn't allow you to do that directly since its default value for `availableColors` is private.  However, its `availableColors` property is public, so you could construct a dummy `BlockPicker` and extract the default value it used.  For example:

```dart
final defaultAvailableColors =
    BlockPicker(
      pickerColor: Colors.black,
      onColorChanged: (_) {},
    ).availableColors;

...
          child: BlockPicker(
            ...
            availableColors: availableColors ?? defaultAvailableColors,
            ...
          ),  
...
```

In the long-term, I would file an issue against `BlockPicker` and request that either the defaults be made public or that they're used when the arguments are `null`.

Comment: I have requested the relevant developer to replace it as follows. https://github.com/mchome/flutter_colorpicker/pull/20/commits/6dabf3bfa70de5585caba892eb92a0ab5a992faa

Comment: I'm using Dart 3.2.5, still that feature is not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if availableColors is a list of Colors but instead of using this code:

```
child: availableColors == null ? BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          ): BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            availableColors: availableColors,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          ),
```

u can use this one:

> if avaliableColors is not null use availableColors if not use
>   defaultColors

```
child: BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            availableColors: availableColors??defaultColors,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          ),
```

defaultColor must be a value like availableColors.

Comment: In this case, the default is `_defaultColors`, which would be private to the library that `BlockPicker` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if I understand your question correctly.

Probably you need to change the class `BlockPicker`. Give a default value to some properties, so you dont need to pass them.

Example:

```
class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String texto;

  MyText({this.texto = "default value"});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(texto);
  }
}
```

And this class, can be used like:

```
// with a parameter, print "my data"
MyText(texto: "my data"),

// no parameter, takes the default, print "default value"
MyText(),
```

---

If you cant change `BlockPicker` maybe you can do something like:

```
child: BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            availableColors: (availableColors == null) 
               ? "your-defaults-color" 
               : availableColors,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          )
```

---

One last way. You can extract that part and call the function:

```
  Widget buildMyText(col) {
      if (col == null) {
          return BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          ); 
      } else {
          return BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: selectedColor,
            availableColors: availableColors,
            onColorChanged: (color) => selectedColor = color,
          ); 
      }    
  }

 // use
 child: buildMyText(availableColors)
```

Comment: I can't change BlockPicker. It comes from an external library.

Comment: I give you other way, but it similar to your own solution.