# Set parameter for a class if variable is not null

Tags: dart

How can set a parameter only if a variable is not null. Is there a null aware operator or technique for this?

Eg:

```
this.startWidget = FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
key: UniqueKey(),
controller: _startController,
enabled: true,
// onChanged: _onChanged,
inputType: InputType.time,
decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Start Time',
),
initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 0),
initialValue: StartinitialValue,
enabled: true,
);
```

Here, I want `initialValue: StartinitialValue` only if StartinitialValue is not null.

I dont want to do the following:

```
if (StartinitialValue == null) {
    this.startWidget = FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    controller: _startController,
    enabled: true,
    // onChanged: _onChanged,
    inputType: InputType.time,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Start Time',
    ),
    initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 0),
    enabled: true,
    );
} else {
    this.startWidget = FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    controller: _startController,
    enabled: true,
    // onChanged: _onChanged,
    inputType: InputType.time,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Start Time',
    ),
    initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 0),
    initialValue: StartinitialValue,
    enabled: true,
    );
}
```

What is the proper way to do what I need?

Comment: In general, you either will need to duplicate the default for the parameter you want to omit or you will need two separate calls.  There are a number of GitHub issues about this (e.g. https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/219, https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1492).

Comment: AFAICT, [`FormBuilderDateTimePicker`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_form_builder/latest/flutter_form_builder/FormBuilderDateTimePicker/FormBuilderDateTimePicker.html)'s `initialValue` is of type `DateTime?` with a default value of `null` anyway, so in your case you could just have a single call that uses `initialValue: StartinitialValue` unconditionally.

Comment: And also see [using the default value if the parameter is null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61261624/).

Answer (score 1):

A parameter can be either nullable or non-nullable in Dart. I think here what you need is using optional parameter which will set your initial value.

https://zaiste.net/posts/dart-optional-function-parameters/

example code:

```
class MyClass { 

final TimeOfDay startinitialValue;

MyClass(startinitialValue = const TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 0))

}
```

Comment: Here, `FormBuilderDateTimePicker` is not a user defined function. It's from a third party library which I have no control over. Can you explain with code?

Answer (score 1):

No. The only way not to pass an argument in a function call is to have no argument in the call. You can't have an argument expression which is ignored if it's null.

The one thing you can do is to figure out what the function you call will do if you omit the argument, and then pass the same value yourself ... if that is possible (it might not be, if the function uses a default value that you cannot create from outside the same library).

In this case you are in luck. Looking at [the constructor](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_form_builder/latest/flutter_form_builder/FormBuilderDateTimePicker/FormBuilderDateTimePicker.html), *not* passing the optional `initialValue` is *exactly the same* as passing `null` as a value. (It's an optional nullable parameter with no default value, which means it has a "default default-value" of `null`).

So, just pass `initiaValue: StartinitialValue` even when `StartinitialValue` is `null`. It works exactly the same as not passing the parameter when the value is `null`.